# How would I manually set the arrow direction of an options menu presented by a UIDocumentInteractionController?

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller, uidocumentinteraction, options-menu

My app includes an options menu for sharing, which is presented when a `UITableViewCell` is long pressed. If the `UITableViewCell` is too high on the screen, the arrow from the options menu is below the `UITableViewCell`. Is there any way to set the arrow direction manually?

The code I use to show the options menu is:

```
self.documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: fileShareURL)

self.documentInteractionController.delegate = self

self.documentInteractionController.UTI = "public.xml"

self.documentInteractionController.presentOptionsMenuFromRect(self.view.frame, inView: self.view, animated: true)
```

where `documentInteractionController` is defined as a class variable with `var documentInteractionController: UIDocumentInteractionController!`, and `fileShareURL` is an `NSURL` pointing to the file I would like to share.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem wasn't the location of my `UITableViewCell`, but where I was presenting the options menu from. My code was presenting the options menu from the top of the screen, not from where the cell was.